# Need help fixing "Image as Planes” color, saturation and brightness. Looks washed out compared to original

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, image, color

I imported an "image as planes” in Cycles and am getting a washed out/lighter version of the original. This is the image and node set-up I currently have.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me fix? Here is the desired outcome that looks fine in Premiere. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the principle BSDF node, just make the roughness 1 and metallic and specular to 0. or use a diffuse bsdf.

Comment: Perfect. Thank You!

Comment: @Todd you should check the checkmark saying the answer worked for you.